# hd0 read error on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

My computer was hanged while it was shutting down and I had to hard reboot the system by pressing the power button. When the system booted back I got the message

```
error: hd0 read error
```

and the system went into grub rescue. When running:

```
grub rescue>ls
```

I get:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4)(hd0,msdos3)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)
```

My system was partitioned into three drives /,/usr and /home.
I can see / and /home when I type:

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos2)/
```

but I can't see /usr in any drives. Or rather:

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos3)/
```

returns `error: unknown filesystem`

I tried using `boot-repair` with the Ubuntu LiveCD. But nothing helped.
I want to recover the OS or at best recover the data in `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

On a Toshiba TECRA changed the value of the BIOS booting configuration from 'OS' to 'all devices' and it solved it.